# Preview current directory in shell

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, zsh, ls

What often happens when I work in a shell - zsh - is that I have `cd`ed somewhere and I want to have a quick look at the directory. Using `ls` may produce a lot of output and leaves it in the terminal. Using `ls | less` is better, however it again leaves traces when I quit `less` all its output is there. Do you have an idea how I can do something like `ls | less` but when I quit `less`, it leaves the terminal screen untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, `less` behaves as you describe - I need to use `less -X` to *disable* this behaviour.

You could try explicitly using the "*alternative screen buffer*" that many terminals implement.

This is used by editors like `vim` / `nano`, so that when quitting, the terminal is restored to how it was before.

Try this:

```
tput smcup
ls | less
tput rmcup
```

If `tput` is unavailable, then try using `echo $'\e[?1049h'` / `echo $'\e[?1049l'` respectively.

Comment: `less -X` does not change anything in this regards for me.

Comment: What about `tput`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that you are using zsh, you can take advantage of zsh builtin tab-completion. You won't get a "long" ls listing, but you can preview names of directories and files by typing "ls " followed by a tab. You'll see what files/directories you could potentially "ls" in your current working directory, and then you can either ls one specifically, add a "-l filename" to view one in particular in detail, or just hit "Control-u" to clear the line you're on and prepare to enter a different command, and the tab-completion suggestions will disappear.

For instance, when I "ls "[TAB] on one of my VMs, I see:

```
user@fbsd:~% ls
.cshrc                   .mailrc                  .ssh/
.login                   .profile                 .zshrc
.login_conf              .rhosts                  code/
.mail_aliases            .shrc                    inventory.hw.gather.sh*
```

When I hit Control-u, the suggestions below my command line disappear.

Comment: Thank you. that is true, however I want something more generic. That, for example, I could do `ls -lah`, etc.